# NetLogo : Keep turtles moving continuously till the end

Tags: netlogo

Readers,

I'm a beginner in NetLogo. Please help me in solving few issues with my code that is below:

1. I'm getting an error "You can't use tick in a turtle context, because tick is observer-only.
2. I need to get tick value updated after each turtle go all three of "arrive-reception, arrive-triage, go-drroom".
3. the rest of people is not moving around the arrive reception, arrive triage is running.

   ```
   to setup-people
     set-default-shape turtles "person"
     set destination ( patch-set patch -2 34 patch 8 34 ) 

     create-turtles uninfected
     [ set color blue
       allocate-turtles        
     ]

     create-turtles infected
     [ set color red
       allocate-turtles
     ]

   end

   to allocate-turtles
     if (pcolor = 9.9 and any? turtles-here)
     [
     set size 1.5
     set heading 0                                                                                                                          
     setxy int random-xcor int random-ycor
     ]    
   end

   to go
     move-people
     arrive-reception
     arrive-triage
     go-drroom
     tick
   end

   to move-people
     ask turtles [
     rt 360
     forward 1
    ]
   end

   to arrive-reception
     ask n-of (random count turtles) turtles
     [
     if windows = 1
     [
      move-to patch -2 34
      ifelse not any? turtles-here
      [ wait wait-time ]
      [ wait-in-queue ]
     ]      
     ]
   end

    to wait-in-queue
      set arrival-time ticks
     bk 1
     if any? other turtles-here
       [ wait-in-queue ]
     wait wait-time
    if ticks - arrival-time > wait-time
    [ set arrival-time 0
      fd 1 ]
   end

   to arrive-triage
    if triage = "Open"
     [
      move-to patch 26 11
      if any? other turtles-here
       [ wait-in-queue]
      wait wait-time
      move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = 109 and not any? other turtles-here ]
      wait wait-time 
      ]   
    end

    to go-drroom
      move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = 128]
      if ( min-one-of other turtles in-radius 5 [distance myself] != nobody)
      [
       move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = 129]
      if ( min-one-of other turtles in-radius 5 [distance myself] != nobody)
       [
        move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = 5]
        if any? seats with [turtles = nobody]
          [
            move-to one-of max-n-of 6 neighbors [seats]
          ]
       ]
     ]
     wait wait-time
     die
     end
   ```

Thanks.

Comment: how to keep the turtles in queue as a line one behind another n served fifo  manner

Answer (score 1):

First, some basic programming tricks - don't write so much before trying to debug. If you make a small change and check it, then it's easy to work out where the error is. The first draft of a procedure can be as simple as:

```
to go-drroom
end
```

and then fill in the details of what happens in the procedure later.

Typically this error is because you forgot to close a bracket somewhere. That is, one of the procedures starts with `ask turtles [ ...` and there is no ] so NetLogo is still thinking that the code applies to turtles. However, I can't see an obvious missing ].

But you do have a conceptual problem. The term `context` is used in NetLogo to refer to who is asking the code to be done and to whom. So `ask turtles [ forward 1]` is the observer asking the turtles to move and is an observer context procedure. You are not thinking about what context you are in when writing the procedures, and this is probably what is setting off your error.

In the `go` procedure, you first call `move-people`. This does `ask turtles [ ]` so is (appropriately) from the observer context. Then you call `arrive-reception` and it is also okay.

But then you call `arrive-triage` and `go-drroom` still from the observer context and have commands like `move-to`. Who is being asked to move? You don't have `ask turtles ...`. On the other hand, the procedure `wait-in-queue` has commands like `move-to`, but it is fine because it is only called from within an `ask turtles ...` in the `arrive-reception` procedure.